# EF Context has unexpected stored procedure > Function mapping

Tags: entity-framework

When I import a sql stored procedure like this into my database first model

```
Declare@A int =0;
Declare@B int =0;
Declare@C int =0;

Set @A = (select Count ...)
Set @B = (select Count ...)
Set @C =  IsNull((@A + @B),0)
Select @C As UseCount
```

Why would EF produce a method signature in the generated context with a return type of

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>
```

and not just a return type of `int` as I would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "strongly type" the return set. One way, declare a table variable with the column NOT NULL

```
Set @A = (select Count(*) From Tasks)
Set @B = (select Count (*) From Tasks)
Set @C =  IsNull((@A + @B),0)
--Select @C As UseCount 
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(UseCount int NOT NULL)
INSERT @MyTableVar SELECT @C
SELECT TOP(1) UseCount FROM @MyTableVar
```

May be able to shorten that up a little.

This will change the generated method from

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> TestProc()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("TestProc");
}
```

to

```
public virtual int TestProc()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("TestProc");
}
```

**SORRY, CORRECTION** - although the generated method looks good, it doesn't actually work. The second version is returning the RETURN code from the stored procedure, not the scalar result required. Adding the table variable into the stored procedure does have an effect on the 'Get Column Information' button of the Entity Framework Add Function Import wizard - the Nullable column changes from true to false. However, if you set the return type to Scalars the generated method still uses Nullable<>.

You can hand-code the method in a partial class of your DbContext like so:

```
public partial class OnModelCreatingEntities
{
    public virtual ObjectResult<int> TestProc2()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<int>("TestProc");
    }
}
```

This gives the correct result and is not over-written when the classes are regenerated. It also works with the original transact-sql.

Comment: yep - was about to say that when the return type is not Scalars type it returns -1, otherwise it's back to ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>. Thanks anyway, it was a really interesting suggestion